# MYSQL query table joins gives duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the tables movie, movie_client, language_movie, language, subtitle_movie and subtitle

I want to select all movies with their subtitle and language where client_id (in movie_client) is 1

```
        SELECT * FROM movie 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_client 
        ON movie.movie_id = movie_client.movie_client_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN client
        ON movie_client.client_movie_id = client.client_id

        LEFT OUTER JOIN language_movie
        ON movie.movie_id = language_movie.movie_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN language
        ON language_movie.language_id = language.language_id

        LEFT OUTER JOIN subtitle_movie
        ON movie.movie_id = subtitle_movie.movie_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN subtitle
        ON subtitle_movie.subtitle_id = subtitle.subtitle_id

        WHERE client.client_id=1
```

this does nog work cause i get duplicate rows i tried inner joins as swell but it just wont work. Can anyone help me with the right query?

Comment: Move the `client.client_id=1` condition to the it's `ON` clause to get true left join behavior. As it is now you get regular inner join result.

Comment: If a movie has subtitles in two languages, or is in two languages, you will get that movie twice. It's the expected result. If you want each movie only oncy, you have to describe how to chose language, subtitle etc.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try :

```
    SELECT distinct m.movie_id, lm.language_id, sm.subtitle_id FROM movie m
    INNER JOIN movie_client mc
    ON m.movie_id = mc.movie_client_id 
    INNER JOIN client
    ON mc.client_movie_id = c.client_id

    INNER JOIN lm
    ON m.movie_id = lm.movie_id
    INNER JOIN language l
    ON lm.language_id = l.language_id

    INNER JOIN subtitle_movie sm
    ON m.movie_id = sm.movie_id
    INNER JOIN JOIN subtitle s
    ON sm.subtitle_id = s.subtitle_id

    WHERE client.client_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    FROM movie 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_client 
    ON movie.movie_id = movie_client.movie_client_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN client
    ON movie_client.client_movie_id = client.client_id
```

should be INNER JOINs you don't need all movies

```
    SELECT * FROM movie 
    INNER JOIN movie_client 
    ON movie.movie_id = movie_client.movie_client_id 
    INNER JOIN client
    ON movie_client.client_movie_id = client.client_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN language_movie
    ON movie.movie_id = language_movie.movie_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN language
    ON language_movie.language_id = language.language_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN subtitle_movie
    ON movie.movie_id = subtitle_movie.movie_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN subtitle
    ON subtitle_movie.subtitle_id = subtitle.subtitle_id

    WHERE client.client_id=1
```

Check [this to understand difference INNER and OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Comment: as @jarlh stated if movie has 2 languages or subtitle has 2 languages you get rows doubled. Which language should be left if there are 2?

Comment: yes i know but i get the same result from everything twice so one movie with one language twice the output

Comment: @YouandiHossen, Can you add some sample table data, the current result, and the wanted result?

Comment: Try to remove the OUTER JOINs one by one till duplicates exist to figure out which table provides the duplicates.

Comment: current result:

client = 1
movie_id = 1 
movie = 'movie1'
language_id=1
language = ENG

client = 1
movie_id = 1 
movie = 'movie1'
language_id=2
language = NED

client = 1
movie_id = 1 
movie = 'movie1'
language_id=1
language = ENG

client = 1
movie_id = 1 
movie = 'movie1'
language_id=2
language = NED

Wanting::
client = 1
movie_id = 1 
movie = 'movie1'
language_id=1
language = ENG

client = 1
movie_id = 1 
movie = 'movie1'
language_id=2
language = NED

Comment: It goes wrong by adding the language without it works when i add those the results duplicate

Comment: You can add ON language_movie.language_id = language.language_id and language.language_id=1 to leave just one

Comment: If you need bioth languages then you correctly get 2 rows with one movies but 2 languages. If you still need one row choose which language to see or define somehow rule how to select necessary language